# Regex validation for birthdate in the format of mm/dd

Tags: validation, regular-expressions

I have a custom text field with a max length of 5 characters and I'm trying to use regex to enforce a date entered in the format of `mm/dd`. Two digits, then a "/", followed by two digits. I was trying some examples, but cannot seem to get the regex correct. Here is an example of one that I tried:

`NOT(REGEX(Birthday__c , "(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape your slash character (`/`).

```
NOT(
    REGEX(
        Birthday__c ,
        "(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\\/(0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])"
    )
)
```

Note that your expression still does not block values such as `02/31`. You may want to work to craft your expression such that it checks each month individually.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. What I still notice is that if I enter something like 1/1 it will allow it. I'm trying to strictly enforce 2 digits followed by a slash followed by 2 digits. So, in the example of 1/1, the validation should catch that and enforce the date to be entered as 01/01.

Comment: Yeah your question mark characters do that. Remove those.